# how to add "product filter by price " in opencart

Tags: opencart

i am trying to add product filter by price in opencart, So how to do this?

also add this featured in product page

Comment: You are trying means You have such an extension and only do not know how to incorporate it to the OpenCart, or You want this feature and You do not have such an extension?

Comment: See http://tonytemplates.com/blog/how-to-make-your-own-filters-and-show-them-on-your-site-in-the-opencart/ . I believe Filters must be done manually with the default installation. This means that you can create a filter "0-50" but you must **manually** add all products within that price range to that filter.

Answer (score 3):

Follow this steps you can easily add the Price filter for your open cart front end page

Filter I    Category → Filter-->Insert--> add filter.
            Give--> 1000,2000 and more.
             Now Save Filters.

Filter II   Extension-->Modules-->Click Filter.
            Maintain with Column Left
             Status enabled.

Filter III  Catalog -->Products-->Click Edit 
            Go to Links-->Type Filter Amount
            If Product Price 2500 ,then maintain the  filter value price (2000 – 3000) Range.
Regards
Megala

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it is unnecessary to add the price filter. It is possible to generate the price range filter automatically for products listing when the customer access any category in your store.

I use an advanced products filters module(include price range filter) for my store > http://www.myluvme.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=88_95.

It really help my customers focus in on what they are looking for which will create more sales.

The mod worked out of the box with the default theme and only needed some minor tweaks to work with my custom theme which the developer did for me immediately. i like that it builds upon the framework of oc.

It should be useful to boost your online sales too. I recommend you to try it. You could find it at:

http://www.ocaddons.com/product/opencart-module-advanced-products-filters-module-include-price-range

Answer (score 0):

Unlike many other shopping carts there is no a built-in filter in OpenCart that could be considered a normal usable e-commerce store filter unfortunately. The OpenCart filters thing is a super clumsy functionality and it's not very clear for users how to administer it. In our company we use an extension called Brainy Filter http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=19184 They have it for both OpenCart versions but of course you should go with 2.x rather then the old 1.5.x one. All other filters we tried appeared to be either just junk or had very messy interfaces.